# Sorting is not working with Pageable in Springboot

Tags: sorting, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement Pagination and sorting by using Pageable in Springboot, JPARepository. Somehow sorting is not working. I am including my code below where I have controller, service class, repository, entity etc. I've also posted my console output where you can see only limit is appended but not "order by" to sql query. I dont know what I am missing here as I've followed everything as documented in Spring.io for pagination&sorting.

**TestController:**

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public class TestController {

        @Autowired
        private TestService testService;

        @GetMapping("/list/{fileId}")
        public Page<Test> list(@PathVariable Integer fileId, @RequestParam Map<String, String> queryMap) throws Exception {
            return testService.getTestList(fileId, queryMap);
        }

    }
```

**TestEntity:**

```
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "fileId")
    private Integer fileId;

    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String fname;

    @Column(name = "lname")
    private String lname;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getFileId() {
        return fileId;
    }

    public void setFileId(Integer fileId) {
        this.fileId = fileId;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}
```

**TestRepository:**

```
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {

    Page<Test> findByFileId(@Param("fileId") int fileId, Pageable pageable);

}
```

**TestService:**

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepo testRepo;

    public Page<Test> getTestList(Integer fileId, Map<String, String> queryMap) {

        Sort sort = Sort.by(Direction.valueOf(queryMap.get("direction")), queryMap.get("property"));

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(Integer.parseInt(queryMap.get("pageNo")) - 1,
                Integer.parseInt(queryMap.get("pageSize")), sort);

        Page<Test> testDetails = testRepo.findById(id, pageable);

        return testDetails;
    }

}
```

**GetRequest:**

```
http://localhost:8080/cms/test/list/0?pageNo=1&pageSize=5&direction=DESC&property=fname
```

**ConsoleOutput:**

As we see in the console output there is no order by appended in the sql query even though the sort object is passed to the JPARepository Query. Can I get some help here.

```
[nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select test0_.id as id1_21_, test0_.address as address2_21_, test0_.email as email3_21_, test0_.fname as fname4_21_, test0_.lname as lname5_21_ from test test0_ where test0_.fileId=? limit ?

[nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
```

Comment: Your code looks quite ok for me. Have you debugged your code and made sure that all parameters are set right?

Comment: Have you tried your code but with a different kind of query? Because your query always returns a single specific result (`where test0_.id=?`) and neither paging nor sorting has a meaning to a search by primary key query. Maybe try it to a `findAll` method and see what the resulting query is.

Comment: @Patrick Yes I've debugged the code and verified all the parameters are passed.

Comment: @pleft The query is working fine for pagination, but not for sorting "order by" is not appended in the JPA query.

Comment: Yes but your query is some kind “special”. You search by primary key which always returns a very specific record the one with the requested is. Probably spring/hibernate does some kind of optimization when converting the Jpa query to sql query and wipes out the order by clause since it is not needed at all. Can’t you try with a findAll query instead of findById ?

Comment: @pleft Sorry for this confusion, actually I was not searching on primary key, its different ID, i've updated the code, for one FileId there will be many records, and I need to apply pagination and sorting on those records. So I dont think findAll() will work for me.

Comment: To sort the record you have to use "OrderBy" with methods in repository interface. Like this [ "findByFileIdOrderByFieldId" ]. Let me know on which field do you want sorting, I will share answer in detail.

Answer (score 2):

On your Repository extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` as below:

```java
public interface TestRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Test, Integer> {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue trying to page and sort a [named query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries)

Only paging a named query works in my case, paging + sorting not.

So I have added sorting directly in my named query, being the sorting column not dynamic, and the paging from my `@Service`:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, perPage);
Page<Customer> pageCustomer = prospectRepository.findAllNotDeletedSortByName(pageable);
```

My named query in my `orm.xml`:

```
<named-query name="Prospect.findAllNotDeletedSortByDenomAzienda">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[SELECT cr 
                   FROM Customer cr 
                  WHERE cr.deleted = false
                  ORDER BY cr.name ASC ]]>
    </query>
</named-query>
```